# Only Display posts with specific custom field value within string or array

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

Ok so I have everything displaying correctly but if there are terms other than the conditional term `'Non-Marine'` within the field `'value'` for the custom field `"item_tags"` it does not display those.

Basically I'm looking for posts with :
 1. Custom **post_type**  - ait-dir-item
 2. Custom **field location** - annapolis
 3. Custom **field item_tags** - Non-Marine (this value is within other terms seperated by commas)

I'm also not sure if these values are strings or arrays?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'ait-dir-item', 
               'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'location',
                        'value' => 'annapolis'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'item_tags',
                        'value' => 'non-marine'
                    )
                ),
                'orderby' => 'title', 
                'order' => 'ASC',
               'posts_per_page' => 300 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title('<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h3>');
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

Thanks for any input!

Cory-

Comment: I think this is a problem related to how WordPress builds queries, please add the necessary tags to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you're mistaking tags for custom fields - "Custom field item_tags which are comma separated"... sounds like a tag to me.  Sorry if I'm wrong.

In which case, that part of it would look like this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'item_tags',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'non-marine'
    )
)
```

The whole thing would look like this:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'ait-dir-item', 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'location',
            'value' => 'annapolis'
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'item_tags',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'non-marine'
        )
    )

    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'ASC', ... etc
```

If you wanted comma separated tags, you should really be using [custom taxonomies (codex here)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) anyway!